# Generate multiple builds in one makefile

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile

I want to have my unit test built along with my project every time I run make. I tried to do this with the following code in my Makefile:

```
DEPS = Parallel.cpp Resistor.cpp Series.cpp Source.cpp
TEST = Parallel.cpp Resistor.cpp Series.cpp Test.cpp

resistor: $(DEPS)
        g++ -std=c++11 -o resistor $(DEPS) -I. -g
test: $(TEST)
        g++ -std=c++11 -o test $(TEST) -I. -g
```

Yet when I look at the directory I only see ./resistor and not ./test.... BTW any advice for improving my makefile in other ways is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following rule as the first rule in your `Makefile`:

```
all: resistor test
```

Then run `make`:

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++11 -o resistor Parallel.cpp Resistor.cpp Series.cpp Source.cpp -I. -g
g++ -std=c++11 -o test Parallel.cpp Resistor.cpp Series.cpp Test.cpp -I. -g
```

Per [the `make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html):

> By default, `make` starts with the first target (not targets whose
>   names start with ‘.’).